# how to make the animation clickable in android

Tags: android, animation, imageview

I've made a simple animation for an image and I set the event OnClick on the image to make a toast. The problem is that I made the image started doing the animation on the onCreate and I made set the image to be clicked and fire the toast but the problem is that the image isn't clickable, but if I press on the original position of the image, the toast is started (the image is not moving with the animation)

thx for your help

this is the animation code in anim folder (translate.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="-80%p"
        android:toXDelta="80%p"
        android:duration="20000"
        android:repeatCount="100"
        android:repeatMode="restart"



        />


</set>
```

and this is the Activity Class

```
package com.example.animatest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ImageView image01;

private long aefe;
private ImageView image1;
private ImageView image2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    image01 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    final Animation animTranslate1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            R.anim.translate);

    image01.startAnimation(animTranslate1);

    image01.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();

        }
    });

}

}
```

Comment: What you mean with this: `but if I press on the original position of the image, the toast is started (the image is not moving with the animation)` can you add some screenshots? its hard to understand.

Comment: what i mean is if click on the image the toast will start but if i click on the image when it is doing the animation nothing happen

Comment: to be more clear for u the image doing animation from left to the right in the screen i want the user if he click on the image when it is doing the animation the toast will start

Comment: @FoamyGuy i saw this question but i didnt know how to do it

Comment: @MohammedAsmar you asked that question, It is nearly 100% identical to this one. The only part that changed were values in the translate animation. And the changes will not lead to a different answer. Please do not post the same question twice.

Comment: i am sorry for that but i didnt get the answer when i post it that's why i post the question again and i am looking for this answer for long time :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the entire animation, your view remains at the old location (location when the animation just started). It is just drawn in another spot. You'd have to move your animated view after your animation ends:

Register a listener to your animation.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html

In your onAnimationEnd implementation, modify your Activity's layout so that it resembles the final state/layout of your animation.

**Update after your comment:**

The only way I see of doing this is by creating your own custom Animation in Java code and implementing your custom Animation's 'protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t)' method. For example, in our app we have an animation that actually **moves** a View around instead of just **drawing** it at a different location. E.g. below is an example of an Animation that increases or decreases the actual height of a View:

```
public class ViewHeightAnimation extends Animation {
    private final View  view;
    private final float diffHeight;
    private final int   startHeight;

    public ViewHeightAnimation(View view, float diffHeight, int startHeight) {
        this.view = view;
        this.diffHeight = diffHeight;
        this.startHeight = startHeight;

        setDuration(200);
        setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        android.view.ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams layoutParams = (android.view.ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.height = Math.round(startHeight + (diffHeight * interpolatedTime));
        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean willChangeBounds() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Your Animation would be different, but would be using the 'getLayoutParams()' and 'setLayoutParams()' as well to modify the View's (ImageView's) position and change layoutParams.topMargin and layoutParams.leftMargin appropriately.

If you are not concerned about Android 2.x or lower, using the ObjectAnimator (3.0 or higher) or ViewPropertyAnimator (3.1 or higher) is a better solution, as was mentioned in other answer earlier.

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: thx but this is not what i mean i dont want onAnimationEnd
waht i want is when the animation start i can click on the animation

Comment: I updated my answer above. Hope this helps :)

Comment: thank u but where i have to but this code (class)
i am sorry but i dont have any idea about this 
thank u any way

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
final Animation animTranslate1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.translate);
animTranslate1.setFillAfter(true);
image01.startAnimation(animTranslate1);
```

If that does not work then you'll have to use the newer Property Animation framework (which was pointed out in the answer to your previous duplicate question)

[See here to learn about it](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html)

Answer (score 0):

The way you animate your imageView is only move its appearance, so actually your imageView is still at the old position. There's not an easy way to do what you want, with this type animations. You should consider to use [ObjectAnimators](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html) ...